# Is it possible to check dynamically by Java code if google-services.json exists inside app module?

Tags: android, firebase

Is it possible to check dynamically by Java code if `google-services.json` exists inside app module?

I need to check it because I'm experimenting about dynamically initializing things on an application.

Can't find any info about this in Google or here.

Comment: Do you mean, your code will look for the file when your app is installed and running on an Android device?

Comment: u want to check in android studio or apk?

Answer (score 0):

No because your Code will not run Until you finish `Gradle Build`. and it will give you error Error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
   Searched Location: 
  C:\Users\...\app\src\debug\google-services.json
  C:\Users\...\app\google-services.json
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you mean checking it programmatically while app is running?
if so 
there is no way to check if the `google-services.json` file exists or not 
because the `google-services.json` file gets parsed and its values get added to an xml which you have access to: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin
 you could check if the api key is exist or not

```
activity.getResources().getString(R.string.google_api_key);
```

in your case

```
int checkExistence = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("google_api_key", "string", mContext.getPackageName());

if ( checkExistence != 0 ) {  // the resouce exists...
    result = true;
}
else {  // checkExistence == 0  // the resouce does NOT exist!!
    result = false;
}
```